# Other ViewController for searchResultsUpdater

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

How can I set another `ViewController` for the `searchResultsUpdater`?
I tried to do it like this, but the results are not updating.

```
let searchNav = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchControllerNav") as! UINavigationController
    let vc = searchNav.topViewController as! PageMenuVC
    let searchVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchVC") as! SearchVC
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: vc)
    vc.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchVC
```

Here's my PageMenuVC:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    let searchVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchVC")
    controllerArray.append(searchVC!)

    let testVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test")
    controllerArray.append(testVC!)

    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .viewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 20.0/255.0, blue: 20.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.orange),
        .bottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .menuItemFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)!),
        .menuHeight(40.0),
        .menuItemWidth(90.0),
        .centerMenuItems(true)
    ]

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
    pageMenu!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}
```

In `SearchVC` I have this function:

```
//MARK: Filter
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredUsers = allUsers.filter { user in
        return user.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
    collectionView.reloadData()
}




//MARK: SearchResultDelegate
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text!
    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchBarText)
    self.searchController = searchController
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

If you need more info, let me know!

Comment: Hope it helps! https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep the instantiated view controllers in a (private) property of the `self` view controller: If you set it as the the delegate to `vc.searchController.searchResultsUpdater`, this is only a `weak` reference, therefore if you do not store `searchVC` in `self`, it will be destroyed too soon (just at the end of the code block). The same holds for searchNav (but I think this will be presented, therefore I'll skip it below):

```
class MyVC : UIViewController {
    var searchVC:UIViewController?
    // ...
    func XYZ() {
        let searchNav = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchControllerNav") as! UINavigationController
        let vc = searchNav.topViewController as! PageMenuVC
        // Store searchVC in property:
        self.searchVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchVC") as! SearchVC
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: vc)
        vc.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchVC
        self.present(searchNav, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas, No it's not working. But I just added more code to my question. Thanks

Comment: Please check (via breakpoint etc.) if the methods `filterContentForSearchText` and `updateSearchResults` are called at all, and if `collectionView` is the correct view to be updated.

Comment: No it's not being called.